# Подскажите как правильно оформить функцию QUERY(sql-запрос) в Google Sheets ? Выдает такую ошибку (прикрепляю)

Tags: sql, запрос, google-spreadsheet

Мне нужно из всех данных забрать только столбцы "B,C,D,I,K,L,O,R" при условии, что в строках столбца "D" будут значение только "orders". Подскажите как правильно оформить запрос?
Сейчас такой : " =QUERY('Продажи (исх.)'!$A2:$X;"select B,C,D,I,K,L,O,R where D is 'orders'") ". Причем протестировал еще orders is not null - все нужные столбцы отдает!

Спасибо!!
[image: текст ошибкитекст ошибки]

Comment: Откуда ты родил оператор IS в качестве строкового сравнивателя? [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY('Продажи (исх.)'!$A2:$X;"select B,C,D,I,K,L,O,R where D = 'orders'")
```

Просто замени в формуле "is" на "=" и всё заработает.
is только если
where A is not null или
where A is null

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]